# Returning datetime in specified format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'nl_NL')

from datetime import timedelta
def get_maandnaam(maand):
    if maand == 1: return 'januari'
    if maand == 2: return 'februari'
    if maand == 3: return 'maart'
    if maand == 4: return 'april'
    if maand == 5: return 'mei'
    if maand == 6: return 'juni'
    if maand == 7: return 'juli'
    if maand == 8: return 'augustus'
    if maand == 9: return 'september'
    if maand == 10: return 'oktober'
    if maand == 11: return 'november'
    if maand == 12: return 'december'
    
datum = pd.to_datetime("05" + " " + get_maandnaam(int(1)) + " " + "2000", format = "%d %B %Y")
print(datum)
```

What surprises me is that in the `print()` the outcome is `2000-01-05 00:00:00`. I expected `5 januari 2000`. Why is this and could this be fixed?

Comment: look up `dt.strftime`

Comment: oof. use a dictionary install of all of those `if` statements

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change to :

```
datum = pd.to_datetime("05" + " " + get_maandnaam(1) + " " + "2000", format = "%d %B %Y").strftime('%d %B %Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

`pd.to_datetime(in, format=format)`
Returns date object parsed from `in`, assuming format `format`.

It then can be printed in whatever format you wish, including the format it was parsed from:

```py
print(datum.strftime("%d %B %Y"))
```